# How can I set up my somfy controlled blinds to go up and down at specific time periods?

Tags: home-automation

Our kitchen at work gets really hot when the sun sets, so I want the RF Somfy controlled blinds to automatically go down at some pre-programmed time (ideally I could automate this by date and season since the sunset and sunrise will change all year).

I found an [INSTEON adaptor](http://www.smarthome.com/318276I/I-O-Linc-INSTEON-to-Somfy-RF-Drape-Control-Kit/p.aspx) which will talk RF to the blinds, but I don't know anything about INSTEON or how it works.  My best bet seems to buy the INSTEON [desktop software](http://www.smarthome.com/_/Timers_Automation/Advanced_Automation_Software/Beginner_Installs_10_minutes/Smarthome/_/r/1TD/23L/1sn/nav.aspx) but there are 3 different kinds, so not sure which one to get.

I have a computer in my office I could install the software on, but how would it talk to the INSTEON adaptor in the kitchen? (Our offices are on a separate electrical circuit from the kitchen - not sure if that's how INSTEON works)

Comment: I wonder if http://superuser.com might have more input on the desktop software part of your question.

Comment: @B_Mitch I just don't get how the INSTEON stuff works. Is it talking over the voltage? The website makes it seem like there's a wireless mesh network going on.

Comment: I don't have any experience with INSTEON, but it sounds like it may be using something similar to X10: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_%28industry_standard%29

Comment: @Michael Pryor - Its all standalone and needs extra bits to control it via TTL plugs or trigger plugs I suppose. Like i showed you need to buy extra stuff. If you really want to control via computer you need the wireless transmitter and reciever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to send Infrared signals to the Adapter. So you will also need to buy a remote for another 50USD.

So to use it from another computer somewhere else in the office you first need to get this

[USB Wireless adapter for your PC](http://www.smarthome.com/2448A7H/HouseLinc-INSTEON-Desktop-Software-with-Portable-USB-Adapter/p.aspx)

Then you need to get an access point to bridge the wireless to a electric

[This AP - i am not sure but you might need something more- read more here](http://www.smarthome.com/2443/Access-Point-INSTEON-Wireless-Phase-Coupler/p.aspx)

But i think [this temperature controller](http://www.smarthome.com/24950A7/I-O-Linc-INSTEON-High-and-Low-Temperature-Threshold-Kit/p.aspx) will be better- as you dont have to program any thing just set some temps and viola- but again- you might need to buy something extra to connect to your blinds.. read more

Comment: +1 for temp control idea instead of a schedule. In the same vein, perhaps responding to light conditions would be a good route too.